# Javascript regular expression for phone number validation.(String contains only at least 1 digit, 0 or more spaces and '-'

Tags: javascript, regex, phone-number

Currently I have an expression:

```
numMatches = phone.match(/[^\d\s\-]/gi);

if (numMatches != null) {
    alert(invPhnNo);
}
```

This gives an alert if any characters other than digit, space and hyphen are entered. But still accepts if only hyphen and spaces are given without a single digit.
Now i would want it to alert if atleast a digit is not there. So a digit is mandatory. Can have zero or more spaces and hyphen and no other characters.

Can anyone suggest an approach to this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validations

Answer (score 1):

You could either use the standard regexp refered to by Trever, but you could also simply run another `.match(/\d+/g)` on the string and if both succeed, you can be sure that it complies with your requirements and also has at least one digit.